# Flatten / normalize json array of objects with jq

Tags: json, relational-database, jq

I have a large json array of objects. Each object contains a `foreignKeyId`, a `url`, (optionally) a `urlMirror1`, and (optionally) a `urlMirror2`.

Here's a sample:

```
[
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 1,
    "url": "https://1-url.com"
  },
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 2,
    "url": "https://2-url.com",
    "urlMirror1": "https://2-url-mirror-1.com",
  },
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 3,
    "url": "https://3-url.com",
    "urlMirror1": "https://3-url-mirror-1.com",
    "urlMirror2": "https://3-url-mirror-2.com"
  }
}
```

I want to normalize this json to something like below:

```
[
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 1,
    "primariness": 1,
    "url": "https://1-url.com"
  },
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 2,
    "primariness": 1,
    "url": "https://2-url.com",
  },
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 2,
    "primariness": 2,
    "url": "https://2-url-mirror-1.com",
  },
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 3,
    "primariness": 1,
    "url": "https://3-url.com"
  },
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 3,
    "primariness": 2,
    "url": "https://3-url-mirror-1.com",
  },
  {
    "foreignKeyId": 3,
    "primariness": 3,
    "url": "https://3-url-mirror-2.com"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do something like this using `jq`? If not, any other suggestions to accomplish this quickly without writing too much custom code? This only needs to be run one time, so any kind of hacky one-off solution could work (bash script, etc.).

Thanks!

**Update:**
`primariness` should be derived from the key names (`url` => `1`, `urlMirror1` => `2`, `urlMirror2` => `3`. Order of the keys inside any given object is insignificant. There is a fixed number of mirrors (e.g., there is never a `urlMirror3`).

Comment: Great question, very intriguing. However it's unclear whether the order of keys (`foreinKeyId`, `url`, `urlMirror1`, `urlMirror2`) is reliable or _primariness_ should be parsed from the key names (e.g. `urlMirror1`->2, ..., `urlMirrorN`->N+1); or if it is okay to hardcode key names (`urlMirror1` and `urlMirror2`) in the JQ program.

Comment: agree with @oguzismail, really good JSON query. If you're interested, I also can provide an alternative solution for this query using `jtc` tool.

Comment: @Dmitry, not sure about OP but I'd love to see how this can be handled with **jtc**. I've written a couple JQ programs, but both are long and unable to be extended for similar use cases.

Comment: @oguzismail, let's wait until there's an accepted JQ answer and then I'l post **jtc** version

Comment: @oguzismail, I just answered your question in **Update** at the bottom of my question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, then luciole75w's answer below would do the trick.

Comment: @oguzismail, posted `jtc` version for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple script with hardcoded number of mirrors and primariness. Hope it will do the trick.

```
jq '
    map(
        { foreinKeyId } +
        (
            { primariness: 1, url },
            (.urlMirror1 // empty | { primariness: 2, url: . }),
            (.urlMirror2 // empty | { primariness: 3, url: . })
        )
    )
' input.json
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that OP has limited the query from generic down to a more specific criteria, the answer provided by @luciole75w is the best (most probably), refer to that one.

Now, for @oguzismail, this is a generic `jtc` approach (which will handle an arbitrary number of `"urlMirror"s`) made of 3 JSON transformation steps (**updated solution**):

```
<file.json jtc -w'<foreignKeyId>l:<f>v[-1]<urlM>L:<u>v[^0]' \
               -i'{"url":{{u}},"foreignKeyId":{f}}' /\
               -w'[foreignKeyId]:<f>q:<p:0>v[^0][foreignKeyId]:<f>s:[-1]<p>I1' \
               -i'{"primeriness":{{p}}}' /\
               -pw'<urlM>L:' -tc
[
   { "foreignKeyId": 1, "primeriness": 1, "url": "https://1-url.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 2, "primeriness": 1, "url": "https://2-url.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "primeriness": 1, "url": "https://3-url.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 2, "primeriness": 2, "url": "https://2-url-mirror-1.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "primeriness": 2, "url": "https://3-url-mirror-1.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "primeriness": 3, "url": "https://3-url-mirror-2.com" }
]
bash $
```

#### Explanation and visualization:

- all the 3 steps can be observed in a "slow-mo":
1. for each found `"foreignKeyId"` and each `"urlMirror"` found within the same record extend (insert into) the array with `{"url":... , "foreignKeyId": ...}`:

```
<file.json jtc -w'<foreignKeyId>l:<f>v[-1]<urlM>L:<u>v[^0]' \
               -i'{"url":{{u}},"foreignKeyId":{f}}' -tc
[
   { "foreignKeyId": 1, "url": "https://1-url.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 2, "url": "https://2-url.com", "urlMirror1": "https://2-url-mirror-1.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "url": "https://3-url.com", "urlMirror1": "https://3-url-mirror-1.com", "urlMirror2": "https://3-url-mirror-2.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 2, "url": "https://2-url-mirror-1.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "url": "https://3-url-mirror-1.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "url": "https://3-url-mirror-2.com" }
]
bash $
```

2. now insert `"primariness": N` records based on the index of the occurrence of the `foreignKeyId`:

```
<file.json jtc -w'<foreignKeyId>l:<f>v[-1]<urlM>L:<u>v[^0]' \
               -i'{"url":{{u}},"foreignKeyId":{f}}' /\
               -w'[foreignKeyId]:<f>q:<p:0>v[^0][foreignKeyId]:<f>s:[-1]<p>I1' \
               -i'{"primeriness":{{p}}}' -tc
[
   { "foreignKeyId": 1, "primeriness": 1, "url": "https://1-url.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 2, "primeriness": 1, "url": "https://2-url.com", "urlMirror1": "https://2-url-mirror-1.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "primeriness": 1, "url": "https://3-url.com", "urlMirror1": "https://3-url-mirror-1.com", "urlMirror2": "https://3-url-mirror-2.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 2, "primeriness": 2, "url": "https://2-url-mirror-1.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "primeriness": 2, "url": "https://3-url-mirror-1.com" },
   { "foreignKeyId": 3, "primeriness": 3, "url": "https://3-url-mirror-2.com" }
]
bash $
```

3. and final step (`-pw'<urlM>L:'`) - rid of all redundant `"urlMirror"`s records.

*Optionally*: if there's a requirement to sort all the records within the top array as per the OP's example, then this additional step will do: `-jw'[foreignKeyId]:<>g:[-1]'`

PS. it so happens that I'm also a developer of the `jtc` unix tool

Comment: Oguz, could you return the favor? I'd love to see the JQ (generic) version you came up with.

Comment: The one I wrote was the same as the accepted answer, I stopped working on the generic one as OP clarified :/ Peter might post a neat one though, I'll follow the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general solution, that is, it will handle arbitrarily many urlMirrors.

For the sake of clarity, let's begin by defining a helper function that emits a stream of {foreignKeyId, primariness, url} objects for a single input object:

```
def primarinesses:
  {foreinKeyId} +
    ({primariness:1, url},
     (to_entries[]
      | (.key | capture( "^urlMirror(?<n>[0-9]+)")) as $n
      | {primariness: ($n.n | tonumber + 1), url : .value } )) ;
```

The solution is then simply:

```
[.[] | primarinesses]
```

which can also be written with less punctuation as:

```
map(primarinesses)
```

Comment: @Dmitry - FYPI (?)

Comment: graceful :)) (y)